# Laravel api в респонсе отдать код без тела

Tags: php, laravel

Есть laravel, debugbar. Роут прописанный в Api.php

**Задача.** Вывести только http код с пустым телом.

**Проблема.**

При `return response()->json(null, 403);`  выводится {}

При `return response(null,403)` страница снаружи пустая, но внутри какая-то огромная лапша из link,styles, js.  Видимо от дебагбара или еще от чего.

Как ничего не выводить, только http code?

Comment: `return response()->json(null, 204);` ?

Comment: @РустамГимранов я использую с другим кодом, выводит {}

Comment: Тогда вопрос в чем заключается? 204 - *HTTP_NO_CONTENT*, 403 - *HTTP_FORBIDDEN*. `response()->json` для ответов API

Comment: Вы маршрут API во вкладке браузера открываете?

Comment: @РустамГимранов в Rest клиенте. Вопрос в том, что как мне отдать http код, без каких либо выводов на экран/ в клиент. Т.е. без body.